# Annotation in Java Interface

Tags: java, interface, junit

Is there a way say,

```
import org.junit.Test;

public interface ITest {
    @Test
    public void runTest();
}
```

when I inherit this in a class it will automatically do this

```
public class Test implements ITest {
       @Test
       public void runTest() { }
}
```

instead of `@Override`?

Comment: What is it you want to gain by that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default annotations in Java are not inherited. If an annotation type has the meta-annotation `@Inherited` then it will be, but I don't think [`@Test` does](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Test.html).